# Moving a shaper using mouse click in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to make a shape move left if I leftclick my mouse , and go right if I click right. The following code is not working. What have I done wrong ?

```
from tkinter import  *
import time

tk =Tk()
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=500,  height=500,)
tk.title("Drawing")

xbat = 0

def clickL(event):
    xbat =- 1
    print(xbat)


def clickR(event):
    xbat =+ 1
    print(xbat)


canvas.bind("<Button-1>", clickL)
canvas.bind("<Button-3>", clickR)


canvas.pack()

bat =  canvas.create_rectangle(150, 500,  300,  480, fill="black")


while True:
    canvas.move(bat,xbat,0)
    tk.update()

    time.sleep(0.01)



canvas.mainloop()
```

Comment: You are only changing a local variable named `xbat`, not a global one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
from tkinter import  *

tk =Tk()
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=500,  height=500,)
tk.title("Drawing")

def clickL(event):
    xbat = -1
    print(xbat)
    xmove(bat,xbat)


def clickR(event):
    xbat = 1
    print(xbat)
    xmove(bat,xbat)

def xmove(object,x):
    canvas.move(object,x,0)


canvas.bind("<Button-1>", clickL)
canvas.bind("<Button-3>", clickR)


canvas.pack()

bat =  canvas.create_rectangle(150, 500,  300,  480, fill="black")


canvas.mainloop()
```

It is typically bad practice to have a `while True` loop in tkinter code, it doesn't give the GUI time to update. Instead I've changed you code so that each click event calls a separate xmove function.

An alternative approach could be to change the coordinate of the object when the button is clicked then have a periodic `update` function which re-draws/moves the objects to their update positions. This periodic update could be achieved with the tkinter `.after` method.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was stuck here for hours . I will try not to use while loop .

Comment: @JuliJuli You are welcome. If this solved your problem, remember to click the tick to accept the answer